# Is couchbase java SDK really thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock, couchbase

Today I was facing some issues with the java SDK 2.1.1 targeting my couchbase server.
The client is doing a lot of reads on couchbase. At one point, one thread gets locked (I can see one CPU core at 100%) and is never released.
I am doing synchronous calls. It is only get calls. How come does it create a deadlock ?

Any input appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Romain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually not a deadlock.
The view I am querying is returning too many results. As a consequence, it leads to a timeout.
I find it still pretty strange that the thread is not released ...

Anyway, I will go for async calls. Maybe it will help ! It seems to support timeout handling.

Comment: try adding pagination support to your view. You have to set result size before making call...see docs how to do that http://blog.couchbase.com/pagination-couchbase